# Library for printing text in strings in colums of given width for console output

Tags: java, string-formatting

I am looking for a library/API that seperates strings by spaces an line-breaks to appy sensible line wrapping to lines that exceed a given limit. For instance, if I set the Formatter I am looking for to column width 10 and add the following strings:

```
    String s1 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n";
    String s2 = "The quick\nbrown fox jumped over\nthe lazy dog.";
```

I expect output similar to:

```
    The quick
    brown fox
    jumped
    over the
    lazy dog.
    The quick
    brown fox
    jumped
    over
    the lazy
    dog.
```

i.e. Line breaks already marked by the input text should be honoured and additional line-breaks schould be added when necessary.

Here is a quick and clumsy implementation by myself to illustrate a raw baseline of my expectations:
[Column Formatter Whip-Up](http://pastebin.com/FGwSYCZ9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the WordUtils.wrap(String, int) method from the Apache commons-lang library.